# Multiple range selection in DataGrid with Shift key pressed (Flex 3)

Tags: datagrid, flex3, selection, range

Could we do multiple range selection like in DataGrid of Gmail?

In standard, flex DataGrid does not support this. All the selected items in the previous range will be discarded if we select another range of rows (with Shift key pressed).

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe we shold subclass DataGrid and override selectItem() function in which the old selectedItems will be merged to the new range (need to use an Array merging function).

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `:allowMultipleSelection="true"`